# Gutenberg - Looking to inject block data into wp_head on save

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have created a code editor block where the user can insert CSS styles.  Rather than having these save to the post_content and show up in the body, I would like for them to be injected into the head.

I have done this in the past using PHP hooks but cant seem to figure out how to translate that to the new JS API hook format

I found this for adding through functions.php:

```
function hook_css() {
    ?>
        <style>
            .wp_head_example {
                background-color : #f1f1f1;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'hook_css');
```

But I would like to achieve this on a block level basis using dynamic data from the user input. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to save the CSS as post meta and use the post meta to insert the CSS into the header.

See the [Gutenberg tutorials on meta boxes](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/metabox/) as a guide to updating post metadata through Gutenberg.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Simons answer I was able to get this working perfectly.

Combined with his suggestion of storing the data as post meta and this [tutorial](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/metabox/meta-block-1-intro/) I was able to complete my project.